# ParseFacebookUtils throws an error after I upgraded Parse to library to version 1.13.0

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I just upgraded my parse Android package from version 1.9.1 to the latest version offered by Parse. I added FacebookUtils, TwitterUtils and everything and the app seems to work except when I wanna use the Facebook login.
It gives me this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Callback already registered for <facebook>: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils$1@1fce48e9
```

I haven't changed anything and in fact when I restore back to my old 1.9.1 version everything works. 
So is this a bug in new Parse library? How can I fix this?

**Edit**

Logcat:

```
0   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Callback already registered for <facebook>: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils$1@2a6d3adb
1   at com.parse.ParseAuthenticationManager.register(ParseAuthenticationManager.java:35)
2   at com.parse.ParseUser.registerAuthenticationCallback(ParseUser.java:1089)
3   at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils$ParseUserDelegateImpl.registerAuthenticationCallback(ParseFacebookUtils.java:562)
4   at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(ParseFacebookUtils.java:109)
5   at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(ParseFacebookUtils.java:92)
6   at com.me.bit.bitme.Views.LoginActivity.onFBLoginButtonClicked(LoginActivity.java:170)
7   at com.me.bit.bitme.Views.LoginActivity.access$200(LoginActivity.java:49)
8   at com.me.bit.bitme.Views.LoginActivity$3.onClick(LoginActivity.java:90)
9   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4803)
10  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19981)
11  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
13  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
14  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5430)
15  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
16  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
17  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:913)
18  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
```

Comment: add your code complete logcat

Comment: add your LoginActivity code also

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize `ParseFacebookUtils` into an **Application** class, not in a **AppCompatActivity** class.

You may create a java class and call it **Configs**, set its name in the **Manifest**:

```
    <application
        android:name=".Configs"
        ...
```

The Configs class would look like this:

```
public class Configs extends Application {
…

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(this); 

    …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize `ParseFacebookUtils` into an Application class.

However, Application crash can be avoided simply by try catch `IllegalStateException`.

```
try {
       ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(this);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d("MyApp", "Seems like ParseFacebookUtils already initialized");
        }
```